# How to put dynamically-generated n-amount of <div>s in <li>

Tags: php, html

Hello :) I realy need your help here. I dynamically generate list of items but instead of putting each item in separate `<li>` I want to get something like this:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <div>$pt</div>
      <div>$pt</div>
      <div>$pt</div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <div>$pt</div>
      <div>$pt</div>
      <div>$pt</div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Here is code I have:

```
<ul class="some-ul-class">
    <?php $itemCount = 3; ?>
       <?php $i=0; foreach ($p->getItems() as $pt): ?>
           <?php if ($i++%$itemCount==0): ?>
              <li class="item">
           <?php endif; ?>
                 <div>$pt</div>
              </li>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

But as the result I get structure like this:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <div>$pt</div>
   </li>
   <div>$pt</div>
   <div>$pt</div>

   <li>
      <div>$pt</div>
   </li>
   <div>$pt</div>
   <div>$pt</div>
</ul>
```

Thank you for help

Comment: Your result can't come from the example code above.

Comment: Unfortunately they do, I inspected element and saw that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ul class="some-ul-class">
<?php $itemCount = 3; ?>
   <?php $i=0; foreach ($p->getItems() as $pt): ?>
       <?php if ($i%$itemCount==0): ?>
          <li class="item">
       <?php endif; ?>
             <div>$pt</div>
       <?php if ($i%$itemCount==2): ?>
          </li>
       <?php endif; $i++; ?>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

You can try this.

Comment: Ok, I tried it and it is really weird because now I get 2 <div>s in list and third one outside :S

Comment: I see :) But it still gives same result :S I realy can't figure out what is wrong with it. Because if I want to fit every item in separate <li> it works like charm. I am struggling with this problem for hour already :(

Comment: Then, I hope it is last editing. Take a look at new code please :)

Comment: Thank you for your answers I got it to work by checking in second if $i%itemCount==3

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul class="some-ul-class">
  <?php $itemCount = 3;
    $i=0;
    foreach ($p->getItems() as $pt):
      if ($i%$itemCount==0):
        echo '<li class="item">';
      endif;
        echo "<div>$pt</div>";
      if ($i%$itemCount==2):
        echo '</li>';
      endif; $i++;
    endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ok, I tried it and it is really weird because now I get 2 <div>s in list and third one outside :S

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<ul class="some-ul-class">
    <?php $itemCount = 4; ?>
    <li>
    <?php $i = 1; foreach ($p->getItems() as $pt): ?>
        <?php if ( $i % $itemCount == 0): ?>
            </li><li>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php $i++; ?>
        <div><?php echo $pt; ?></div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
     </li>
</ul>
```

This generates:

```
<ul class="some-ul-class">
    <li>
        <div>1</div>
        <div>2</div>
        <div>3</div>
    </li><li>
            <div>4</div>
            <div>5</div>
            <div>6</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/YsQKHj)

Comment: I saw demo and was very happy until I tried to apply it to my code. I really do not understand why it doesn't workthat it why I am asking here. Oh, yes, I tried your code and I got only two <div>'s in <li> and that's all :S

Answer (score 0):

Your code will not achieve nested DIVS in LI because you need a multidimensional array to nest the items within the container. The solution is to break the initial DB result set in to chunks with array chunk.

This just splits your array (1,2,3,4,5,6) to ([0] => array(1,2,3), [2] => array(4,5,6)

Run through the loop below you will get two LI with 3 nested DIV. The code is not tested but should be something like operational.

```
<?php 

$items = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15);         
// Your initial item array

$rows = 3;                           
// Number of rows in each li 

$items = array_chunk($items, $rows); 
// Final nested array in blocks of 3

if ($items) {       
    echo "<ul class='some-ul-class'>\n";        
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {           
        echo "<li class='items'>\n";            
        foreach ($item as $divs) {
            echo "<div>{$divs}</div>\n";
        }           
        echo "</li>\n";             
    }       
    echo "</ul>\n";
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you but I need output like: <li> 1 2 3 </li> <li> 4 5 6 </li> <li> 7 8 9 </li> and so on

Comment: Surely that is reliant on the object you are submitting to the loop. To create an unordered list with nested divs inside the lists automatically you will have two arrays.

Comment: As the other comment said the result is actually not possible from you loop. The last one in my code will work.

Comment: The problem being you would have to have arrays of three and do the loop inside the li. You need to use array_chunk

Comment: Thank you but I can't have an array because I get items from the DB and it can be from 0 to infinity items there.

Comment: Are you fetching one row at a time from the database?
How are you doing a for each if it is not an array?

Comment: Yes I do, and if I want to put every element in different <li> it works good.